# Simulate data based on negative binomial regression coefficient

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model

I'm trying to simulate a dataframe with columns `x` and `y` based on a real-world dataset. Fitting a negative binomial regression model onto the real world dataset produced a coefficient of `0.1922` with a standard error of `0.0268`.

Now I want to create an artificial dataframe based on this finding to run some follow up analyses. So far I've done the following to generate hypothetical `y` values:

```
y <- rlnorm(1000000) # generate 1,000,000 numbers from log normal distribution
y <- y*10 # multiply by ten to get more realistic numbers
y <- round(y, digits = 0) # round to whole number
hist(y) # take a look
```

How can I use the results of the negative binomial regression to map my simulated `y` values onto simulated `x` values?

---

FYI: If you need it, you can find a good overview of the negative binomial regression [here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/negative-binomial-regression/)

Comment: Not sure, but MASS has an application for simulating negative binomial data:
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/MASS/html/rnegbin.html 
Does this meet your needs?

Comment: Thanks, but the rnegbin function only generates a single vector of data points from a negative binomial distribution. I need to generate a dataframe of two variables with a relationship similar to that which I found in a real-world dataset I analysed.

Comment: This is really not yet a programming question but rather displays a lack of statistical knowledge and should have been posted on CrossValidated.com

Comment: @Jason is your question, what information do I need to simulate data according to a negative binomial regression model where $E[Y|X] \propto \alpha + \beta X$? and $Y$ has a negative binomial distribution?

Comment: @AdamO Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2):

If a response $Y_i \in \left\{0, 1, \dotsc \right\}$ given a vector of covariates $X_i \in \mathbb{R}^p$ follows a negative binomial regression model (with a $\log$ link) and coefficients $\beta$ and an (inverse) dispersion parameter $\theta$ then $E(Y_i|X_i) = \exp( X_i \beta) = \mu_i$, $\text{Var} (Y_i | X_i) = \mu_i + \mu_i^2/ \theta$ and

$$
P(Y_i = y | X_i) = \binom{y+\theta - 1}{y} \left(\frac{\mu_i}{\mu_i + \theta} \right)^y \left(\frac{\theta}{\mu_i + \theta} \right)^{\theta} 
$$

In R, to simulate a vector of responses, given a design matrix `X` you could write

```
eta = X %*% beta
y = rnbinom(length(eta), mean = exp(eta), size = theta)
```

Comment: I see "eta" in the R code but no Greek letter`eta` in the explanation. It should be possible to "back calculate" the parameters from mean and variance.

Comment: Eta commonly used for the "linear predictor" in a regression.  It's equal to $\log \mu$ in this case.  In the question, it was not explained how the regression was fit, but one shouldn't need to "back calculate" anything -- all that is needed is the coefficient and the dispersion parameter estimates.

Comment: @Andrew M Thanks, this is helpful. Could you please explain what you mean by "design matrix X" ? At present, I only have a vector/column of simulated data that I want to apply a negative binomial regression equation to, ultimately creating a bivariate negative binomial distribution (i.e., where the relationship between x and y takes the shape of a negative binomial distribution).

Comment: In that case I don't understand what you are trying to ask.  I don't know what a "bivariate negative binomial distribution" is, nor do I think it has a common definition.  I don't  understand what it means to say "that relationship between x and y takes the shape of a negative binomial distribution" . There are many senses in which a distribution could have a shape.

Comment: @Andrew M Sorry for the confusion. Can you please explain where design matrix X comes from? That is where I get lost. I have read into it here (https://www.mathematica-journal.com/2013/06/negative-binomial-regression/) but I am confused as to how to generate it in R.

Comment: I agree that "bivariate negative binomial distribution" is not a proper term. What I mean is that when I plot my simulated variable x and simulated variable y on one plot, the points should appear to be in a negative binomial distribution. At the moment I have only been able to simulate my variables independently so that a density plot of x displays a neg bin distribution, a density plot of y displays a neg bin distribution, but plotting the relationship between the two displays a purely linear relationship (e.g., y = m*x + b).

Comment: When you say "shape", do you mean a scatter plot of Y on X resembles the probability mass function of a negative binomial? `x = runif(1000, max = 20); y = dnbinom(floor(x), prob = .4, size = 4); plot(x, y)`? I'm having trouble why you'd want to do this -- for one, the PMF is discontinuous step function, rather than a continuous density.  I suggest you open a new question and provide background **why** you want to do this, because this whole exercise smells ill-posed to me.